# Using 'discard' in GLSL 4.1 fragment shader with multisampling

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, multisampling

I'm attempting depth peeling with multisampling enabled, and having some issues with incorrect data ending up in my transparent layers.  I use the following to check if a sample (originally a fragment) is valid for this pass:

```
float depth = texelFetch(depthMinima, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), gl_SampleID).r;
if (gl_FragCoord.z <= depth)
{
    discard;
}
```

Where `depthMinima` is defined as

```
uniform sampler2DMS depthMinima;
```

I have enabled `GL_SAMPLE_SHADING` which, if I understand correctly, should result in the fragment shader being called on a per-sample basis. If this isn't the case, is there a way I can get this to happen?

The result is that the first layer or two look right, but beneath that (and I'm doing 8 layers) I start getting junk values - mostly plain blue, sometimes values from previous layers.

This works fine for single-sampled buffers, but not for multi-sampled buffers. Does the discard keyword still discard the entire fragment?

Answer (score 2):

> I have enabled GL_SAMPLE_SHADING which, if I understand correctly, should result in the fragment shader being called on a per-sample basis.

It's not enough to only enable `GL_SAMPLE_SHADING`. You also need to set:

```
glMinSampleShading(1.0f)
```

> A value of 1.0 indicates that each sample in the framebuffer should be indpendently shaded. A value of 0.0 effectively allows the GL to ignore sample rate shading. Any value between 0.0 and 1.0 allows the GL to shade only a subset of the total samples within each covered fragment. Which samples are shaded and the algorithm used to select that subset of the fragment's samples is implementation dependent.
>
> – [glMinSampleShading](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMinSampleShading.xhtml)

In other words `1.0` tells it to shade all samples. `0.5` tells it to shade at least half the samples.

```
// Check the current value
GLfloat value;
glGetFloatv(GL_MIN_SAMPLE_SHADING_VALUE, &value);
```

If either `GL_MULTISAMPLE` or `GL_SAMPLE_SHADING` is disabled then sample shading has no effect.

There'll be multiple fragment shader invocations for each fragment, to which each sample is a subset of the fragment. In other words. Sample shading specifies the minimum number of samples to process for each fragment.

If `GL_MIN_SAMPLE_SHADING_VALUE` is set to `1.0` then there'll be issued a fragment shader invocation for each sample (within the primitive).
If its set to `0.5` then there'll be a shader invocation for every second sample.

```
max(ceil(MIN_SAMPLE_SHADING_VALUE * SAMPLES), 1)
```

Each being evaluated at their sample location ([`gl_SamplePosition`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_SamplePosition.xhtml)).
With [`gl_SampleID`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_SampleID.xhtml) being the index of the sample that is currently being processed.

> Should discard work on a per-sample basis, or does it still only work per-fragment?

With or without sample shading `discard` still only terminate a single invocation of the shader.

Resources:

- [ARB_sample_shading](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_sample_shading.txt)
- [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader)
- [Per-Sample Processing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Per-Sample_Processing)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't help (I do have GL_MULTISAMPLE enabled, btw). Should discard work on a per-sample basis, or does it still only work per-fragment?

Comment: @Vallentin: According to the spec: "Any static use of [gl_SampleID] in a fragment shader causes the entire shader to be evaluated per-sample." So those functions should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem when using depth_peeling on a multi-sample buffer.

Some artifacts appears due to the depth_test error when using a multi_sample depth texture from the previous peel and the current fragment depth.

```
vec4 previous_peel_depth_tex = texelFetch(previous_peel_depth, coord, 0);
```

the third argument is the sample you want to use for your comparison which will give a different value from the fragment center. Like the author said you can use gl_SampleID

```
vec4 previous_peel_depth_tex = texelFetch(previous_peel_depth, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), gl_SampleID);
```

This solved my problem but with a huge performance drop, if you have 4 samples you will run your fragment shader 4 times, if 4 have peels it means 4x4 calls. You don't need to set the opengl flags if atleast `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);` is on

> Any static use of [gl_SampleID] in a fragment shader causes the entire
> shader to be evaluated per-sample

I decided to use a different approach and to add a bias when doing the depth comparison

```
float previous_linearized = linearize_depth(previous_peel_depth_tex.r, near, far);
float current_linearized = linearize_depth(gl_FragCoord.z, near, far);

float bias_meter = 0.05;
bool belong_to_previous_peel = delta_depth < bias_meter;
```

This solve my problem but some artifacts might still appears and you need to adjust your bias in your eye_space units (meter, cm, ...)